# Style php echo with css and blank line

Tags: php, css

I´m trying to style the following php echo

```
<a href="" title="<?php 
                            echo"
                           <div class='test'>".$name."</div>'/n'
                           <div class='test2'>".$itemLevel."</div>'/n' 
                            ";
                         ?>">Test Link</a>
```

But i think i don´t insert the div class and the '/n' at the right place. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Why not do it in a more clean way? For example echo only the PHP stuff instead of everything using `<?= `or `?>`. That way you can debug your code properly. Also you do realize you are echoing inside the title?

Comment: Yeah i need this for a tooltip thats why i use it in the title.

Comment: Does the title property render HTML on output? *AFAIK* it is text only.

Comment: i think you are writing the code wrong, you can't write html code inside `title` attribute, share the js tooltip library to check how it works

Comment: i use the jquery tooltip: code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js

Answer (score 0):

You don't echo the HTML content inside the a href's title.

This will work:

```
<a href=""><?php echo"
                           <div class='test'>".$name."</div>'/n'
                           <div class='test2'>".$itemLevel."</div>'/n' 
                            ";
                         ?>Test Link</a>
```

Optimizing your code:

```
<?php echo '
<a href="">
<div class="test">'.$name.'</div>
<div class="test2">'.$itemLevel.'</div>
Test Link</a>';
```

Comment: Because it is for a tooltip i need to have it in the title tag.

Comment: @Hertus, the tooltip can't contain HTML, you can only put text in there.

Comment: Ah ok i understand. But how can i style the echo output in the title tag. if i can´t use html?

Comment: You could use a tooltip library.

Comment: Just like @Script47 said. You can't echo HTML inside the tooltip with HTML built in functions. You should try a tooltip library. Jquery UI has one. https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style

Answer (score 0):

You must encode your html in order to put it into the `title` property

```
<?php
  $title = '<div class="test">'.$name.'</div>' . PHP_EOL .
           '<div class="test2">'.$itemLevel.'</div>' . PHP_EOL;
?>

<a href="" title="<?php echo htmlentities($title); ?>">Test Link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. This sounds good, but it doesn´t seems to work. It doesn´t use the div class in the tooltip, it just appears the div tag and the echo in my tooltip.

Comment: You can't style it this way (using `title` attribute). Use a tooltip library instead.

Comment: Ok i do it with jquery. I can edit the style of the whole tooltip, but i need the specific lines, which i give out with echo, in different colors/size. Could you give me a tip how to handle that?

Comment: Use CSS rules, mate!